# SQL query MAX() function

Tags: sql

```
select ProductID,ProductName,QuantityPerUnit 
from Products 
where Products.UnitPrice=Max(UnitPrice)
```

What is wrong in this query?

I had tried 'having' in place of 'where' tag.

```
select ProductID,ProductName,QuantityPerUnit 
from Products 
having Products.UnitPrice=Max(UnitPrice)
```

it must produce result with max unit price,

```
ProductID   ProductName     QuantityPerUnit
38          Côte de Blaye   12 - 75 cl bottles
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I tried is:

Select Max(UnitPrice) From Products

select Max(UnitPrice) ProductID,ProductName,QuantityPerUnit 
from Products 
Group By ProductID,ProductName,QuantityPerUnit having Max(UnitPrice)>200

Comment: I see no relationship between this query and the question you asked.

Comment: ohh thanks. you are genius, sorry i am novice. I am just trying to learn it. If I am getting max price from my first code then I can use where command on UnitPrice and I will get my result.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1447095/1047996   @GordonLinoff Please see this

Answer (score 0):

If you want the product(s) with the maximum `UnitPrice`:

```
select ProductID,ProductName,QuantityPerUnit 
from Products 
where UnitPrice = (select Max(UnitPrice) from Products)
```

This query:

```
select Max(UnitPrice) from Products
```

returns the maximum `UnitPrice`.
If there are more than 1 products with that price, they will all be returned. 
If you want just 1, you can use `LIMIT 1` or `TOP 1`, depending on the rdbms you use.

Answer (score 0):

Use sub query to find max price

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, QuantityPerUnit 
FROM Products 
WHERE UnitPrice = (SELECT Max(UnitPrice) FROM Products)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply use aggregate function in a where clause unless it's in a subquery.

Try :::

```
select ProductID,ProductName,QuantityPerUnit from Products 
Where  Products.UnitPrice= (select Max(UnitPrice) from Products)
```

If you're using TSQL, then better use

```
select top 1 With ties  ProductID,ProductName,QuantityPerUnit from Products 
Order by  UnitPrice desc
```

This will give you all the products with highest unit price and is efficient since there's no subquery.

Answer (score 0):

can use HAVING clause

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, QuantityPerUnit FROM Products
     GROUP BY ProductID, ProductName, QuantityPerUnit
     HAVING UnitPrice = MAX(UnitPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with your query is that you are mixing aggregation value with raw values in the query.

If you want only one row, I would recommend a different approach:

```
select ProductID, ProductName, QuantityPerUnit 
from Products 
order by UnitPrice desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Although `fetch first` is standard SQL, not all databases support it, so you may need the appropriate syntax for your database.

Comment: @sriRohit . . . There is an `ORDER BY`, so I have no idea what your comment is supposed to mean.